# When does retrieving a Hibernate proxy's id initialize the proxy?

Tags: java, hibernate, lazy-loading

In Hibernate when you retrieve an Entity via a load, if you access that Entity's id accessor it does not initialize the proxy:

```
Property myProp = (Property) session.load(Property.class, myId);
myProp.getId(); // Doesn't load the proxy
myProp.getDescription();  // Loads the proxy from the database hit
```

However, I am unclear what the rules are for loading association proxies.  I was under the impression that when you retrieve an Entity via a HQL query or Criteria the same rules apply.

Each `Property` in my code has a `Company`.  The `Company` is declared as such:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional=false)
@JoinColumn(name = "company_id", nullable=false)
private Company company;
```

However, in my code I'm currently getting N+1 selects when iterating through the `Properties` because the `Company` is being loaded when I call `Company.getId()`.

In both the `Company` and `Property` object the id field is a Long annotated with `@Id`.

Is there some other consideration I'm missing in order to prevent the loading of the `Company` entity?

Comment: The answer is a great start but the first comment is the best answer.  Make sure to read that link that Gennady Shumakher posted.  
Also, if anyone is curious there is a bug in the Hibernate database on this issue that I found: http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-3718

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It does not work as expected simply because of **you have to use property access** instead of field access.

Instead of

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, optional=false)
@JoinColumn(name="COMPANY_ID", nullable=false)
private Company company;
```

Use

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, optional=false)
@JoinColumn(name="COMPANY_ID", nullable=false)
public Company getCompany() {
    return this.company;
}
```

Takes care you can not use property access and field acces at the same time. So **you should choose one approach**.

regards,

Comment: +1 - more detailed explanation is available here: http://www.catalysts.cc/en/blog/ejb-annotations-hibernate-lazy-loading/

Comment: I see, from reading the article it seems like the right approach is actually to change the Company object so that the annotations are all on the getters.  Its more important that the getId() method is annotated rather than getCompany() on Property.

Comment: Java Persistence with Hibernate - (www.manning.com/bauer2) mentions this point in "13.1.3 Understanding Proxies": `As long as you access only the database identifier property, no
initialization of the proxy is necessary. (Note that this isn’t true if you map the
identifier property with direct field access; Hibernate then doesn’t even know that
the getId() method exists. If you call it, the proxy has to be initialized.)`.